# Collection View inside Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, tvos, collectionview

I want to create collection view inside the table view cell for horizontal scrolling of elements. But I have the problem how to fill right my collection views. I need a way to connect collection views with my data.

How can I get and loop through Table View Cells to find needed collection view and return the cells with data?

[image: Collection View in Table View Cell]

Comment: This repo should help https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell

Comment: Good image - this is possible but complex. I would strongly recommend creating a new `delegate / data source` model object for each `UICollectionView` and store those objects in an `Array` which are then referenced in each `UITableView` cell. You will need to connect each `UICollectionView` to the correct model object at runtime. It is doable but there are lots of moving parts so your design will need to be clearly thought out.

Comment: @kye thanks ) I already asked ashfurrow about my problem, but it did not helped me :((

Comment: you can add collectionview in a view then add that view in tableview cell,by this you can run loop easily as well as collectionview and tableviewdelegates will not clash.

Answer (score 1):

below is a general example of how you can pass data to collection views inside your table view cell. Also this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLb8cs11h_g&t=2143s) is a youtube tutorial on this subject.

**Models:**

```
class ListOfParents: NSObject {
var parents:[Parent]?
}

class Parent: NSObject {
var children: [Child]?

static func fetchParents(_ completionHandler: @escaping (ListOfParents) -> ()) {
    //fetch parents data
 }

}

class Child: NSObject {

}
```

**TableView cell:**

```
class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var listOfParents: ListOfParents?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Parent.fetchparents { (listOfParents) in
        self.listOfParents = listOfParents
    }
    tableView.register(CustomParentCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let parentsCount = listOfParents?.parents?.count else {return 0}
    return parentsCount
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomParentCell

    cell.parent = listOfParents?.parents?[indexPath.item]
    return cell
 }
}
```

**Parent cell:**

```
class CustomParentCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


var parent: Parent? {
    didSet {
        // set child value here
    }
}

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return collectionView
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(CustomChildCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "childCellID")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let childrenCount = parent?.children?.count else {return 0}
    return childrenCount
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "childCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomChildCell

    cell.child = parent?.children?[indexPath.item]
    return cell
 }
}
```

**Child cell:**

```
class CustomChildCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var child: Child?
}
```